# Z80 - adding numbers in U2 - settings of register flags

Tags: microprocessor, register, z80

We have Z80. This processor do following operation in U2:
`200 - (-56)`.  What will be values of following register flags:
`S` - the oldest bit of result
`V` - overflow
`C` - carry
`Z` - result is zero.

Now, we know that in U2 we have: `200-(-56) = 200+56 = 00000000(U2)`  Then, I know that:
`S = 0`
`V = 1`
`Z = 1`.
However, when it comes to `C` I am not sure about it. Although, we see the carried bit, I think that in U2 we can ignore it, so `C = 0`.
Am I right ?

Comment: I bet it's not `currying` (which you should know, as your name suggests), but `carry`. I have no idea about this architecture, but usually it is set when the addition is resulting in an overflow.

Comment: According to this `C=1` and rest of flags I correctly set.  Yeah ? http://www.z80.info/z80sflag.htm

Comment: What is 'U2'? I don't recognise that notation.  Is 'U2' an unsigned double-byte? In which case 200+56 = 0000 0001 0000 0000. Otherwise, i agree with @EugeneSh, the carry bit 'does what it says on the can' and it holds the bit carried out of the top of the 8-bit add (a Z80 is a mostly 8bit CPU). Also please correct 'curried' to carried, the C bit os the carry bit.

Comment: The Z80 V and C flags are thoroughly explained at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034566/overflow-and-carry-flags-on-z80

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what U2 is.

In 8-bit binary,

```
      200                          -> 1100 1000
      -56 -> 200                   -> 1100 1000
   -(-56) -> 56                    -> 0011 1000
200-(-56) -> 1100 1000 + 0011 1000 -> 0000 0000 with carry flag
200-(-56) -> 1100 1000 - 1100 1000 -> 0000 0000 with no carry flag
```

The expression 200 - (-56) is problematic for 8-bit. 200 cannot be represented as an 8-bit signed number. While -56 cannot be represented as an unsigned number. That leads to the problem of interpreting what the expression really means. Depending on the context of the actual codes:

If the codes had been compiled to an 8-bit add then:
S = 0, V = 0, C = 1, Z = 1.

If the codes had been compiled to an 8-bit subtract then:
S = 0, V = 0, C = 0, Z = 1.

For 16-bit operation, it is simple:
S = 0, V = 0, C = 0, Z = 0.